# Adding breaks to split a character of strings and convert these new strings into columns

Tags: r, string, vector

What would be the most efficient way to break the character of strings below into multiple columns?

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(47L, 49L, 42L, 45L, 24L, 26L, 
17L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 14L, 50L, 40L, 30L, 20L, 1L, 19L, 
30L, 52L, 49L, 41L, 46L, 25L, 41L, 12L, 13L, 34L, 6L, 10L, 48L, 
38L, 44L, 23L, 38L, 36L, 12L, 28L, 4L, 31L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 
8L, 17L, 29L, 50L, 43L, 37L, 22L, 12L, 15L, 9L, 18L, 33L, 3L, 
27L, 16L, 32L, 7L, 37L, 51L, 35L, 39L, 21L, 33L, 35L, 39L), .Label = c(" 7.00", 
" 7.43", " 7.83", " 7.90", " 8.50", " 9.30", "0.20", "0.27", 
"0.30", "0.37", "0.43", "0.50", "0.53", "0.67", "0.87", "0.90", 
"1.00", "1.50", "1.67", "10.77", "12.00", "13.60", "14.73", "15.93", 
"16.47", "2.00", "2.17", "3.33", "3.53", "3.77", "4.17", "4.63", 
"4.67", "4.83", "5.07", "5.40", "5.77", "6.83", "6.93", "7.00", 
"7.17", "7.43", "7.83", "7.90", "8.50", "9.30", "Final", "A", 
"B", "C", "D", "Semifinal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-70L))
```

I am looking for a data frame that would look like this:

```
Final
2               A  B  
3            7.43  XX
4            8.50  XX
5           15.93  XX
6            2.00  XX
7            1.00  XX
8            0.30  XX
9            0.37  XX
10           7.43  XX
11           8.50  XX
12           0.50  XX
13           0.67  XX
Semifinal
22           A     C
23           7.17  XX
24           9.30  XX
25          16.47  XX
26           7.17  XX
27           0.50  XX
28           0.53  XX
29           4.83  XX
30           9.30  XX
31           0.37  XX
49          B      D
50           7.83  XX
51           5.77  XX
52          13.60  XX
53           0.50  XX
54           0.87  XX
55           0.30  XX
56           1.50  XX
57           4.67  XX
58           7.83  XX
59           2.17  XX
60           0.90  XX
61           4.63  XX
62           0.20  XX
63           5.77  XX
```

I have looked into strsplit() but it is not clear to me how to add the breaks which will be the letters A, B, C and D into this function.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The function strsplit is meant to break strings (single onea, character-vectors of length 1) in different pieces. You could use it for example to split "4.63" into 2 parts: "4" and "63". Which is not what you are looking for I guess.

A character-vector is like an array of strings, which is what you have here. Which is also kind of the problem. Where did you get this data? As it is now, it amounts to little more then something scribbled on a piece of paper, there's no real logic to be found. It's just a row of pieces of text. So first let's split it.
To see where the splits need to be we look for things that don't look like a number, where `is.na(as.numeric(as.character(data$a)))`. To split into groups, we use the `split` function, along with a counter, telling is how many instances of text we've encountered.

```
spl <- split(as.character(data$a), cumsum(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(data$a)))))
```

(this will give you a warning that you can ignore), and the next step is leaving only the numbers:

```
spl <- sapply(spl, function(s) as.numeric(s)[!is.na(as.numeric(s))])
```

(with again, warnings).

## But finally, what to do with this data?

Your suggested end-result is not really a `data.frame`. Of course you can make something that will look like it, but the way you have headers in between the lines is not something R is built for. When I look at it, I understand the last line is a score for "B" against "D", but that's not in the data.frame. The data.frame is just one table, which looks like you've given it column-names "Final", "" and "". And that is the way a computer/R will read it. So not very useful

I think the most useful for this data would be three seperate data.frames, which you just need to assign by hand:

```
Finals <- data.frame(nr=3:13, A=spl[[2]], B="XX")
Semi1 <- data.frame(nr=22:31, A=spl[[5]], C="XX")
Semi2 <- data.frame(nr=50:63, B=spl[[7]], D="XX")
```

Finally, what do the XX's mean, just "not yet known"? Because if you assign it like this, the last column is a character (or a factor), which means if you assign a number to part of it, that number will be converted to a string. I think it may be more useful to assign the designated unknown value that R has: `NA`

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept my answer? Then I'll get more reputation :-) To accept, to the left of my answer, near the top, you should see a grey "V"-sign. Clicking it means accepting my answer as the right one, it should turn green.